# What is the syntax to extract JSON Value from column in Maria DB database?

Tags: mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.2.8.  What is the syntax necessary to extract the value from the key "2" in the below JSON using the JSON_EXTRACT() function

```
{
  "1":"Windows 10",
  "2":"Windows 8",
  "3":"Windows 7",
  "4":"MAC OS"
 }
```

Comment: All JSON functions, including `JSON_EXTRACT`, are documented in [MariaDB KB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/), with usage examples. Please read it.

Comment: They are documented, but there is not any detailed information about the parameters that are needed to pass into the function.  The link you provided simple provides a description of the function versus what you might find in an API doc if you are familiar with what that is.      

Example from the docs:  JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$[1]')     It isn't clear what the $ means for example.

Answer (score 5):

I too found the documentation on the topic quite limited and examples seem to only show how to navigate an array but not an object. Coming from other databases I was also quite confused that I **do not need to cast** to json but operate directly on string.

Example Json:

```
{
  "myKeyA": "Foo",
  "myKeyB": [
    {
      "arrayElementA": "Bar"
    },
    {
      "arrayElementB": "FooBar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can be queried like this:

- `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('...', '$.myKeyA');` returns `"Foo"`
- `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('...', '$.myKeyB');` returns `[{"arrayElementA": "Bar"}, {"arrayElementB": "FooBar"}]`
- `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('...', '$.myKeyB[1].arrayElementB');` returns `"FooBar"`

Where the `...` would be the json input from which we want to get values.

Answer (score 1):

Select JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$[1]')

Here $ means the JSON Document Tree.

The MySQL reference has better examples. However, be careful while pasting and running code from MySQL to MariaDB as MariaDB has a JSON like text based format which is not native binary JSON. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html